# angular scope variable not working in dynamic created html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am newbie in angularjs.

I am creating html on the base of type(business logic). Here some object property working or some not.

**Here my code:-**

```
  $scope.changeObj=$scope.attributes[countInc];

  switch ($scope.changeObj.type) {
        case 'text':
          html+='<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-value="changeObj.type">';
        //Here, changeObj.type is working//
          $scope.rangeShow=true;
          break;
          case 'select':
            html='<select class="form-control" ng-options="optionsO.key as optionsO.value for optionsO in changeObj.options"></select>';
          //Options unable to create. I dont know changeObj.options is working or not.//
            break;
        default:

      }
  eleDiv.html(html);
  $compile(eleDiv)($scope);
```

At the view part `text case` is work but  in  `select case` options are not creating.

Answer (score 0):

Angular directives need to be compiled using `$compile`.
Inject it in your controller and use it as follows :

```
$compile(html)($scope)
```